# Hiding An Element While User Input Doesn't Exist

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My goal is to hide one of my `div`s or all my `p` tags **until** user input actually exists. You can see my attempt below which included a method to change the value of my div state to true or false and whether it's true or false, adjust the `display` to `block` or `none` whether or not the user has inputted anything.

I understand that it would be simple to apply this to a button of some sort but my goal here is to allow React to re-render the `div` or `p` elements once the user has typed something in.

My vision was to measure the user input's length, and if it was greater than 0, show my `div` or `p` tags.

Within my render section of my code, you'll see a `div` with three `p` tags inside. I want those `p` tags, or even the entire div (if it's easier) to **not** show until the user starts typing something within the input box.

```
import React from "react";

class UserInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      showElements: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  badRobot = () => {
    const newInput = this.state.value;
    let badInput = "BLA"
      .repeat(newInput.length / 3 + 1)
      .substring(0, newInput.length);
    return badInput;
  };

  hideElements = () => {
    const userValueLength = this.state.value;
    if (userValueLength.length !== 0) {
      console.log("it worked");
      this.setState({ showElements: true });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label>
            <p>Say Anything</p>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        <div style={{ display: this.state.showElements ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <h3>Good Robot</h3>
          <p>I hear you saying {this.state.value}. Is that correct?</p>
          <h3>Bad Robot</h3>
          <p>I hear you saying {this.badRobot()}. Is that correct?</p>
          <h3>Kanyebot 5000</h3>
          <p>I'm gonna let you finish but Beyonce is {this.state.value}.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserInput;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if the `value` string differs from the empty string sounds like a good condition for showing the `div`.

Instead of keeping a boolean in state you could check the `value` directly in the render method.

```js
class UserInput extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    const showDiv = value !== "";
    const badInput = "BLA"
      .repeat(value.length / 3 + 1)
      .substring(0, value.length);

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label>
            <p>Say Anything</p>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        <div style={{ display: showDiv ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <h3>Good Robot</h3>
          <p>I hear you saying {value}. Is that correct?</p>
          <h3>Bad Robot</h3>
          <p>I hear you saying {badInput}. Is that correct?</p>
          <h3>Kanyebot 5000</h3>
          <p>I'm gonna let you finish but Beyonce is {value}.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<UserInput />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rending.

```
class UserInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            showElements: false
        };
    }

        handleChange = (event) => {
                const value = event.target.value;
            const showElements = value.length > 0 ? true: false;
            this.setState({showElements, value});
        }

        badRobot = () => {
            const newInput = this.state.value;
            let badInput = 'BLA'.repeat(newInput.length / 3 + 1).substring(0, newInput.length)
            return badInput
        }

        hideElements = () => {
            const userValueLength = this.state.value
            if (userValueLength.length !== 0) {
                console.log("it worked");
                this.setState({showElements: true})
            }
        }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <p>Say Anything</p>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
            </form>
            {
                this.state.showElements ? 
              (
                <div>
                <h3>Good Robot</h3>
                <p>I hear you saying {this.state.value}. Is that correct?</p>
                <h3>Bad Robot</h3>
                <p>I hear you saying {this.badRobot()}. Is that correct?</p>
                <h3>Kanyebot 5000</h3>
                <p>I'm gonna let you finish but Beyonce is {this.state.value}.</p>
                </div>

              ): null
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```